# Word for being thought-provoking in a humorous way

Tags: single-word-requests

I need an adjective that implies that the person is profound/thought-provoking but not in a serious way, sort of like the narrator in *The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*.

The words I've found (insightful, provocative, etc.) suggest that the speaker isn't humorous, which is very important. For example, 'Sally is a [word] young woman with a lot of good ideas.'

The word should probably be a little more academic and less conversational.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first few adjectives to enter my mind, as I understand your request,  which mean cleverly humorous, are scintillating, droll, or witty, depending on the desired tone. The Cambridge English Dictionary definitions of each are as follows:

> Scintillating - funny, exciting, and clever
>
> Witty - using words in a clever and funny way
>
> Droll - amusing in an unusual way

From these choices, I would like to emphasize scintillating, but the matter is absolutely a question of tone and desired effect.

Comment: After rereading the question scintillating is definitely the best choice out of these options.

Comment: *Witty* works well here.